# Can't Create Configurable Products with multiple Attributes programmatically

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, programmatically-created, configurable-product

I'm trying to create a configure product with multiple attributes. Here is my code.

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$simpleProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
try {
    $simpleProduct
    //    ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
        ->setAttributeSetId(20) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
        ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
    //    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
        ->setSku('simple99y'.time()) //SKU
        ->setName('test simple product99') //product name
        ->setWeight(4.0000)
        ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
        ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
        ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
        ->setColor(24)
        ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
        ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
        ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
        ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
        ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
        ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
        ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
        ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
        ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
        ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
        ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
        ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
        ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
        ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
        ->setDescription('This is a long description')
        ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
        ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
        ->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                'qty' => 999 //qty
            )
        )
        ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
    $simpleProduct->save();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    error_log( print_r($e->getMessage(),true) );
}

$simpleProduct2 = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
try {
    $simpleProduct2
    //    ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
        ->setAttributeSetId(20) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
        ->setTypeId('simple') //product type
        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
    //    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
        ->setSku('simple98w'.time()) //SKU
        ->setName('test simple product98') //product name
        ->setWeight(4.0000)
        ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
        ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
        ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
        ->setColor(25)
        ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
        ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
        ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
        ->setPrice(22.22) //price in form 11.22
        ->setCost(33.33) //price in form 11.22
        ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
        ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
        ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
        ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
        ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
        ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
        ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
        ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
        ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
        ->setDescription('This is a long description')
        ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
        ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
        ->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                'max_sale_qty' => 2, //Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
                'qty' => 999 //qty
            )
        )
        ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)); //assign product to categories
    $simpleProduct2->save();

} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    error_log( print_r($e->getMessage(),true) );
}

$configProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
try {
$configProduct
//    ->setStoreId(1) //you can set data in store scope
        ->setWebsiteIds(array(1)) //website ID the product is assigned to, as an array
        ->setAttributeSetId(20) //ID of a attribute set named 'default'
        ->setTypeId('configurable') //product type
        ->setCreatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product creation time
//    ->setUpdatedAt(strtotime('now')) //product update time
        ->setSku('configurable96'.time()) //SKU
        ->setName('test config product96') //product name
        ->setWeight(4.0000)
        ->setStatus(1) //product status (1 - enabled, 2 - disabled)
        ->setTaxClassId(4) //tax class (0 - none, 1 - default, 2 - taxable, 4 - shipping)
        ->setVisibility(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH) //catalog and search visibility
        ->setManufacturer(28) //manufacturer id
        ->setNewsFromDate('06/26/2014') //product set as new from
        ->setNewsToDate('06/30/2014') //product set as new to
        ->setCountryOfManufacture('AF') //country of manufacture (2-letter country code)
        ->setPrice(11.22) //price in form 11.22
        ->setCost(22.33) //price in form 11.22
        ->setSpecialPrice(00.44) //special price in form 11.22
        ->setSpecialFromDate('06/1/2014') //special price from (MM-DD-YYYY)
        ->setSpecialToDate('06/30/2014') //special price to (MM-DD-YYYY)
        ->setMsrpEnabled(1) //enable MAP
        ->setMsrpDisplayActualPriceType(1) //display actual price (1 - on gesture, 2 - in cart, 3 - before order confirmation, 4 - use config)
        ->setMsrp(99.99) //Manufacturer's Suggested Retail Price
        ->setMetaTitle('test meta title 2')
        ->setMetaKeyword('test meta keyword 2')
        ->setMetaDescription('test meta description 2')
        ->setDescription('This is a long description')
        ->setShortDescription('This is a short description')
        ->setMediaGallery(array('images' => array(), 'values' => array())) //media gallery initialization
        ->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
                'manage_stock' => 1, //manage stock
                'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
            )
        )
        ->setCategoryIds(array(3, 10)) //assign product to categories
    ;
    /**/
    /** assigning associated product to configurable */
    /**/
    $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->setUsedProductAttributeIds(array(92, 211)); //attribute ID of attribute 'color' and 'Banda' in my store

    $configurableAttributesData = $configProduct->getTypeInstance()->getConfigurableAttributesAsArray();
    error_log("config attributes: " . print_r($configurableAttributesData, true));
    $configProduct->setCanSaveConfigurableAttributes(true);
    $configProduct->setConfigurableAttributesData($configurableAttributesData);

    $configurableProductsData = array();
    $configurableProductsData[$simpleProduct->getId()] = array( //['920'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
        '0' => array(
            'label' => 'Green', //attribute label
            'attribute_id' => '92', //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
            'value_index' => '24', //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
            'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
            'pricing_value' => '21' //value for the pricing
         ),
        '1' => array(
            'label' => 'Johny', //attribute label
            'attribute_id' => '211', //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
            'value_index' => '238', //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
            'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
            'pricing_value' => '4' //value for the pricing
        )
    );


    $configurableProductsData[$simpleProduct2->getId()] = array( //['920'] = id of a simple product associated with this configurable
        '0' => array(
            'label' => 'Grey', //attribute label
            'attribute_id' => '92', //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
            'value_index' => '25', //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
            'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
            'pricing_value' => '25' //value for the pricing
        ),
        '1' => array(
            'label' => 'Johny', //attribute label
            'attribute_id' => '211', //attribute ID of attribute 'color' in my store
            'value_index' => '238', //value of 'Green' index of the attribute 'color'
            'is_percent' => '0', //fixed/percent price for this option
            'pricing_value' => '4' //value for the pricing
        )
    );


    $configProduct->setConfigurableProductsData($configurableProductsData);
    $configProduct->save();
    ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

    $configProduct = null;
    $product_id = $message['product_id'];
    $configProduct = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
    $configProduct->load( $product_id );

    //$stat = file_put_contents("/home/lalani/Desktop/logfile.log", json_encode($configProduct->getData()));

    error_log("success " . $stat);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    Mage::log($e->getMessage());
    error_log( print_r($e->getMessage(),true) );
}
```

and in the result I got this
[Result of above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRMph.jpg)

This shouldn't be like this. There should be two options with Color and one with Banda. However, I have created an configurable product with single attribute but I am not getting success with two attributes. Please help me to figure out the problem.